# Bookmarklets executes slow in the background

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, performance, energy-saving, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet that jumps down (basically sends *end* repetitiously) to scroll down the feed on web sites that uses an "infinite feed" (e.g., Facebook, Quora). For obvious reasons, most of the time I am not interested in watching this bookmark perform 500 *end* with 2 seconds wait inbetween, so instead I send that browser window into the background and continue with something else.

The problem is that when I put the window in the background the bookmarklet practically grinds to a halt. I guess it is some kind of save CPU/energy-thing that is behind this behaviour. Is there a way around this?

Mostly using the bookmarklet i Chrome, and when I wait for it to finish, I often use Firefox instead. Note that I always leave the Chrome tab I run the bookmarklet in visible, and in front of all other Chrome windows/tabs.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout and setInterval are throttled on inactive tabs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#timeouts_in_inactive_tabs

Comment: Is it the same in Chrome? But the tab isn't inactive, it is the front tab of Chrome, although Chrome itself is in the background.

Comment: I don’t know much more than what’s in the link. You could make a chrome extension.